# Python Selenium Прокрутка страницы вниз в спящем режиме

Tags: python, selenium

Всем привет! При написании парсера на Selenium появилась проблема - на сайтах типа авито, где сразу загружается только часть элементов, нужна прокрутка, чтобы парсить остальные, но при установке спящего режима headless = True прокрутка вниз методом send_keys уже не работает, и парсятся только те элементы, которые сразу появились на странице.
Как это исправить? Возможно, есть другой способ работы в спящем режиме, когда прокрутка работает, или другой метод самой прокрутки? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для прокрутки страницы можно воспользоваться js скриптом.
Для прокрутки к концу страницы выполните следующий код:

```py
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Если страница подружается динамически, то можно сделать несколько вызовов данного метода в цикле.
Если же нужно проскролить до определенной координаты, то можете воспользоваться немного другой js функцией:

```py
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

где y - координата высоты